# How to generate angular application using child_processes.spawn() method in a specific directory?

Tags: node.js, angular, nodes

I have recently started to study about node and I wanted the node server should use:

```
ng new my-app
```

To create application without manually typing in the terminal.
I found that we could run command using child_processes.spawn() or child_processes.exec() in node.
I cannot understand why am i not able to do so with the below code?

```
spawn("ng",[join("ng new ", folderName," --directory ", workspaceName)]);
```

I am new to this topic so I would require your help to understand this.

Comment: PS: I am using Windows OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

var child = spawn('npm install -g @angular/cli && cd your directory && ng new my-dream-app', {
  shell: true
});
child.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
  console.error("STDERR:", data.toString());
});
child.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log("STDOUT:", data.toString());
});
child.on('exit', function (exitCode) {
  console.log("Child exited with code: " + exitCode);
});
```

Comment: STDERR: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

Child exited with code: 1

Comment: I was not giving the path correctly. but now I am getting `STDERR: - Installing packages...`

Comment: yeah its not error it's a warning for installing all dependencies for angular just wait to complete process

Comment: got it it takes time!